# Why can't I add Pokémon to my team's gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was leveling up my team's gym to level 8 so I could put my Pokémon in, but after the gym was leveled up, it wasn't showing the add Pokémon button. Why?

I have two other Pokémon in other gyms, so it's not like I've never done it.

Comment: Have you exited and re-entered the gym? Maybe someone snipped the open slot before you could put your pokemon in?

Comment: Yup, I did that, I still see an open spot in the gym but still can't put my Pokèmon in.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Dumb question, but you haven't added pokemon to it already have you?

Comment: Somebody probably is still in the process of adding a pokemon to the gym (hint hint: waiting list)

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you're already in the gym?  it's happened a few times to me, i leveled up a gym thinking i could join but even though there was a hollow dot, there was no button.  i scanned the gym and lo-and-behold i was already there.
starting then, i began the practice of taking a screen shot of my pokemon in the gym as soon as i joined.  before i do my stop/gym loop in the morning, I'll see who got kicked out and needs to be revived, i'll remove their picture from the camera roll.  i'll review the gym pictures that are left and know that i don't need to bother with those gyms.